# Determine top-k values in SQL Server from two different tables

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two tables `table_1` and `table_2` each containing N integer values.

The requirement is to get the `Top 10` integers that are in the tables.

What is the most efficient way of achieving this in SQL Server keeping in view that N is a large 7-digit number?

Had this been a general programming question, max heaps would have been the best data structure for this problem, so I was wondering if there is an alternative that performs similarly in SQL Server.

The only other solution I can think of is to combine these tables by just inserting `table_2` values into `table_1`, issue an `ORDER BY` clause and pick the top 10.

Comment: you can use a temp table instead of inserting one table into the other

Comment: Or a simple union? I have a hard time imagining a case, with the described parameters, where a top on a union would be insufficient.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot: How time efficient would union be on two tables of large size (say 200 million entries)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### For distinct top 10 numbers

```
select top 10 
    res.value
from (
      select value from table_1
      union
      select value from table_2
) res(value)
order by res.value desc
```

### For top 10 numbers at all

```
select top 10 
    res.value
from (
      select value from table_1
      union all
      select value from table_2
) res(value)
order by res.value desc
```

Comment: may be if you have clustered index on column res.value,then no need of order by.

Comment: @KumarHarsh With a clustered index you still need a `ORDER BY`. A nice little article about it: [Order in the court!](http://tkyte.blogspot.nl/2005/08/order-in-court.html)

Comment: Is there any other approach that would be more time-efficient in cases where tables have around 200 million rows each ?

Comment: U can add Actual Execution Plan ( Ctrl+M ) and U'll get recommended indices to add for tables.